# convert mysql config into mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to convert this little piece of code that I did with mysql into mysqli, anyone who can help it will be appreciated alot. I tried a couple of times to do it but I failed but I need to do it with mysqli because mysql in future will be depreciated. . .thank you in advance.

```
<?php

CLASS DB_Class {

  //database selection classes

  function DB_Class($dbname, $username, $password) {
    $this->db = mysql_connect ('host', 'guest', 'dbacess')
    or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server");
    mysql_select_db ($dbname, $this->db) or die ("Could not select database");
  }

  function query($sql) {
    $result = mysql_query ($sql, $this->db) or die ("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
    return $result;
  }

  function fetch($sql) {
     $data = array();
     $result = $this->query($sql);

     while($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ASSOC($result)) {
          $data[] = $row;
     }
          return $data;
   }

   function getone($sql) {
   $result = $this->query($sql);

    if(MYSQL_NUM_ROWS($result) == 0)
      $value = false;
    else
      $value = MYSQL_RESULT($result, 0);
      return $value;
    }
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clash on the query method was probably catching you, I've renamed this _query as you might noticed. I've tested each method to ensure they work also. Let me know if you have any issues.

```
class DB_Class {

    //database selection classes
    private $db;

    function DB_Class($dbname, $host, $username, $password) {
        $this->db = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
    }

    function _query($sql) {
        $result = $this->db->query($sql) or die ("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error());
        return $result;
    }

    function fetch($sql) {
        $data = array();
        $result = $this->_query($sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function getone($sql) {
        $result = $this->_query($sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
            $value = false;
        else
            $value = $result->fetch_row();

        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but its not working....Im getting error on getone() function.

Comment: What's the error? and is the fetch method working? Can you post the code you are using to call the DB_Class as well ?

Comment: `$dbconnect = NEW DB_Class('database','localhost', 'root', 'password');

$frontPageContentsSql = 'SELECT content FROM homepage';
$frontPageContents = $dbconnect->getone($frontPageContentsSql);

echo $frontPageContents;`

Comment: updated the code there if you take the latest, if you see the new DB_Class($dbname, $host, $username, $password) - they didn't match you're input arguments but should now.